# Error in using pkg-config with gcc in fish

Tags: bash, gcc, fish, pkg-config

I use [fish shell](http://fishshell.com/) on Fedora 19. I was trying to compile [this](https://developer.gnome.org/gtkmm-tutorial/unstable/sec-basics-simple-example.html.en) simple gtkmm example.

When I try to compile it using the following command in **fish**:

```
g++ sample.cc -o sample `pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs`
```

it shows the following errors:

```
g++: error: `pkg-config: No such file or directory
g++: error: gtkmm-3.0: No such file or directory
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--cflags’
g++: error: unrecognized command line option ‘--libs`’
```

Whereas, when I use **bash** for the same thing, it compiles correctly. That means pkg-config does fetch the correct flags.

I recently started using **fish** so I don't know what is wrong there. Can someone please help me with this?

Also, this is my first question on stackoverflow. Hello guys.

Thank you.

Comment: Try `yum install pkgconfig`.

Comment: I already have pkg-config. And the code compiles on **bash** but not on **fish**.

Comment: The `PATH` on `fish` seems broken in that case.

Comment: @devnull how do I fix it?

Answer (score 4):

Fish shell uses `( )` for command substitution, rather than the backticks which Bash uses. See: [The Fish tutorial](http://fishshell.com/docs/current/tutorial.html#tut_command_substitutions). This is why it's not working for you, it's unlikely to be an issue with your PATH.

I don't quite understand why, but for some reason if you do simply replace backticks with parentheses, you'll encounter *another* error (where `...` is output from `pkg-config`):

`g++: error: unrecognized command line option '... '`

You can get around that by using the fish command `eval`. So:

`eval g++ sample.cc -o sample (pkg-config gtkmm-3.0 --cflags --libs)`

ought to work.

Answer (score 2):

There is an issue tracking this behavior:
https://github.com/fish-shell/fish-shell/issues/982

Basically, the problem is that fish assumes that arguments are separated by newlines, while pkg-config outputs spaces, which can be seen here:

```
$ echo "'"(pkg-config --cflags eigen3)"'"
'-I/usr/include/eigen3 '
```